# Graph API Filtering on User Resource Error

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I have the following code:

```
var users = await graphClient.Users
            .Request()
            .Header("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")
            .Select("DisplayName, Id, userType, employeeid, accountEnabled, companyName")
            .Filter("userType eq 'Member' AND employeeid ge ' '")
        
            .GetAsync();
```

And it works fine until I add AND companyName ge ' ' to the Filter.  The full filter query reads:

```
.Filter("userType eq 'Member' AND employeeid ge ' ' AND companyName ge ' '")
```

When companyName is added to the filter, I get the error:

Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: 'Code: Request_UnsupportedQuery
Message: Unsupported or invalid query filter clause specified for property 'companyName' of resource 'User'.

Based on Microsoft documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0), this query should work.

The same thing happens when I try to filter on accountEabled. I suspect if I can fix one, I can fix the other.  Am I missing something?

The one caveat is that I am connecting to the GCC High Tenant for the Graph API and some of those resources may not be supported.  I can't find specific documentation for GCC High as to resources available for filtering.  I first want to make sure I'm not making a coding error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add **$count=true** to your query (I'm testing your query in [graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/ru-ru/graph/graph-explorer))

this query not works with error

> Unsupported or invalid query filter clause specified for property
> 'companyName' of resource 'User'.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=userType eq 'Member' AND employeeid ge ' ' AND companyName ge ' '
```

this query works (also with header ConsistencyLevel=eventual)

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$count=true&$filter=userType eq 'Member' AND employeeid ge ' ' AND companyName ge ' '
```

[Advanced query capabilities on Azure AD directory objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries)

For c# code, $count=true you can set by add **[QueryOption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.graph.queryoption?view=graph-core-dotnet)** to query builder, like this:

```
var options = new List<QueryOption>();
options.Add(new QueryOption("$count", "true"));
var users = await graphClient.Users
            .Request(options)
            .Header("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")
            .Select("DisplayName, Id, userType, employeeid, accountEnabled, companyName")
            .Filter("userType eq 'Member' AND employeeid ge ' '")
            .QueryOption("
            .GetAsync();
```

[Query parameters to customize query](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/main/concepts/query-parameters.md)

Comment: Thank you!  I missed the part in the Advanced query documentation where the Consistency Level and Count and what trigger Advanced Queries.